# Add CSS when there's an error

Tags: javascript, css, forms, alert

I have a simple login page that I'm having some trouble with. When you type in incorrect info it just runs an alert, but I want it to add some CSS to the backgrounds of the fields that makes them red. How would I go about editing the following code to do this?

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/JLrQB/)

Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Jeremy Blaz&eacute;</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
        <img src="logo.png" />
        <form name="login">
            <input type="text" name="userid" placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="password" name="pswrd" placeholder="Password" />
            <input type="submit" class="button" onclick="check(this.form)" placeholder="Password" value="Sign in" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <script language="javascript">
    function check(form) {
        if(form.userid.value == "username" && form.pswrd.value == "password") {
            window.open('dashboard/index.html')
        }
        else {
            alert("Error Password or Username")
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this just a toy example or does your app really have usernames and passwords hardcoded into the JS?

Comment: @MartinSmith Just an example for design purposes :P

Answer (score 0):

```
// js
else {
    alert("Error Password or Username");
    document.login.class = "error";
}

// css
form.error input[type="text"], form.error input[type="text"] {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On error, you can do this:

```
form.userid.className = "invalid";
```

CSS

```
.invalid
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your function slightly and run it on form `onsubmit`:

```
function check(form) {

    var valid = true;

    if (form.userid.value !== 'username') {
        form.userid.className = 'error';
        valid = false;
    }
    else {
        form.userid.className = '';
    }

    if (form.pswrd.value !== 'password') {
        form.pswrd.className = 'error';
        valid = false;
    }
    else {
        form.pswrd.className = '';
    }

    if (valid) {
        window.open('dashboard/index.html');
    }

    return false; // return valid; if you want to submit the form once it's valid
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="login" onsubmit="return check(this)">
```

CSS:

```css
#box input.error {
    border: 1px darksalmon solid;
    background: #f0dddd;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JLrQB/1/